# Jack Kirby's Third World

Tags: dc, comics, jack-kirby

What exactly is the Third World, because different stories have given different histories. Jack Kirby's Fourth World Series says that the Third World is the pantheons that arose from the Godwave. Other stories say that the Third World is the planet from which the Godwave origniated.

Is this simply an inconsistency?

Answer (score 2):

It is unknown what Kirby's Third World (or First or Second) were intended to refer to.  This is acknowledged by one of his assistants working on the Fourth World comics, Mark Evanier, in the introduction to the collected edition of the *New Gods* comics.  Evanier and Kirby's other assistant Steve Sherman have conflicting memories of what Kirby said was "fourth" about the world of the New Gods.  It's not clear even whether it was meant as an in-universe or out-of-universe designation, or whether Kirby ever really had a firm idea of what the enumeration meant.